# gathering annotated classes returning generic super type of given class

Tags: java, generics, annotations

In Java 17 I have a method that collects all classes above some class in the inheritance/interface hierarchy that are annotated with a certain interface. For example if `MyClass` implements `Foo`, then if `MyClass` and/or `Foo` and/or `MyParentClass` (the parent of `MyClass`) are annotated with `@MyAnnotation`, all these classes will be returned in a map, the values of which are the instance of `MyAnnotation`:

```java
private static <A extends Annotation> Map<Class<?>, A> getAnnotationsByClassAnnotatedWith(
    Class<?> clazz, Class<A> annotationClass, Map<Class<?>, A> annotationsByClass,
    Set<Class<?>> encounteredClasses) {
  if(!encounteredClasses.contains(requireNonNull(clazz))) {
    encounteredClasses.add(clazz);
    A classAnnotation = clazz.getAnnotation(annotationClass);
    if(classAnnotation != null) {
      annotationsByClass.put(clazz, classAnnotation);
    }
    for(Class<?> classInterface : clazz.getInterfaces()) {
      getAnnotationsByClassAnnotatedWith(classInterface, annotationClass, annotationsByClass, encounteredClasses);
    }
    final Class<?> superClass = clazz.getSuperclass();
    if(superClass != null) {
      getAnnotationsByClassAnnotatedWith(superClass, annotationClass, annotationsByClass, encounteredClasses);
    }
  }
  return annotationsByClass;
}
```

Then I have a convenience "driver" method that kicks things off:

```java
public static <A extends Annotation> Map<Class<?>, A> getAnnotationsByClassAnnotatedWith(
    Class<?> clazz, Class<A> annotationClass) {
  return getAnnotationsByClassAnnotatedWith(clazz, annotationClass, new HashMap<>(), new HashSet<>());
}
```

Logically the annotated classes must be either `MyClass`, an ancestor of `MyClass`, an interface `MyClass` implements, an interface of some ancestor of `MyClass`, or the ancestor of an interface of `MyClass` or one of its ancestors. (Whew!) In short, if I am not mistaken, this means that `MyClass` must be assignable to every returned class; that is, every returned class is a "super" of `MyClass` in generic terms.

So I want to improve the signature to use this:

```java
private static <C, A extends Annotation> Map<Class<? super C>, A> getAnnotationsByClassAnnotatedWith(
    Class<C> clazz, Class<A> annotationClass)
```

**What can I do to these methods to allow the convenience version to return `Map<Class<? super C>, A>`?**

Let's say I change the signature of the larger method accordingly:

```java
private static <C, A extends Annotation> Map<Class<? super C>, A> getAnnotationsByClassAnnotatedWith(
    Class<C> clazz, Class<A> annotationClass, Map<Class<? super C>, A> annotationsByClass,
    Set<Class<?>> encounteredClasses)
```

I also change:

```java
final Class<? super C> superClass = clazz.getSuperclass();
```

The problem now is that my recursive calls won't work. I didn't expect the recursive calls after `clazz.getInterfaces()` to work, but at least after the change above I would want the `clazz.getSuperclass()` recursive calls to work. I think I understand why they don't, but let's try another approach.

I could change the accumulator map parameter back to what it was before:

`Map<Class<?>, A> annotationsByClass`

But now I have a problem trying to `return annotationsByClass`.

You might say that Java generics aren't quite that flexible, and that's probably true.

But since I know that all returned classes are of type `Class<? super C>`, how can I work around this? Is there at least a cast I can do that would produce a warning that I could suppress?

The only way I've found so far is to use `Map<Class<?>, A> annotationsByClass` as the accumulator, cast to `Object`, and then cast to `Map<Class<? super C>, A>`:

```java
return (Map<Class<? super C>, A>)(Object)annotationsByClass;
```

But I am loathe to include such a "hard" hack. At worse I'd like a warning I can suppress.

Or am I mistaken that this logic will only return `Class<? super C>` for the given class `Class<C>`?

Answer (score 0):

None of what you want can be done without 'hackery' (to be a bit more accurate: Without casts that produce warnings about unsafe casting which you can then suppress).

It's not your fault, and not even the fault of generics. It's the fault of the shoddy design of the `java.lang.Class` API, and partly the blame falls on the choice of having Class take generics in the first place.

### Generics? Wrong!

`Class` should not have them.

Class can represent things generics cannot: `int.class` is representing, specifically, the `int` primitive type (it's *not* the same as `Integer.class`!) - yet, `Class<int>` is invalid, so, it doesn't really make sense here.

Generics can represent a great many things that class objects cannot. For example, `List.class` returns `Class<List>` which is extremely annoying (having a raw type *inside* generics is all sorts of bizarre and condemns you to those warnings, pretty much); however, it is not possible to get a `Class<List<String>>` without warning-casts, because that conceptually *does not exist* - a `j.l.Class` instance is not capable of representing generics at all.

Hence, the overlap of 'what can class instances represent' and 'what can generics represent' is your standard venn diagram with all 4 sections:

- Things neither can represent (I dunno; favourite music composer?)
- Things only `Class` can represent (primitive types)
- Things only generics can (types with generics)
- Things both can (non-type-parameterized non-primitive types, such as String).

Hence, *as a general rule of thumb*, when you work with `Class`, you'll run into this, and because the generics are silly to have in the first place, just.. do what you always do when you meet shoddy API: Work around it by turning things into proper types ASAP and SuppressWarnings away the workarounds you have to do to get there.

### Class? APIs broken due to array/generics incompatibility

The API of class is just broken. For example, `getInterfaces()` has the wrong return type; it is written as returning `Class<?>[]` which is just wrong; it should be defined as returning `Class<? super T>[]`. Having generics and arrays is its own problem, but something Class couldn't have helped - `getInterfaces()` predates generics and couldn't be updated in that fashion.

Same applies to `getDeclaredConstructors`, which returns `Constructor<?>[]` instead of `Constructor<T>` - the reason is presumably to do with how generics and arrays don't mix all that well - highlighted particularly well by the fact that `.getSuperclass()` **does** return `Class<? super T>`.

Nevertheless, in your game where the mission is to try to write this without `@SuppressWarnings`: **you just lost that game** - generics are **entirely** a figment of the compiler's imagination, and the API of `j.l.Class` fails to inform the compiler that it returns an array of classes that are guaranteed to be C or a supertype of C, therefore, what you want is now no longer possible.

We could have perhaps snatched victory from the jaws of defeat by using a method like `cast` which checks if some type X is a supertype of type Y, if we provide Y as a `Class<C>` we can then have that method return `Class<? super C>` if it is, and an exception if it isn't - but no such method exists. We can write it ourselves, but you'll find that method cannot be written without warnings / `@SuppressWarnings`.

### Okay, Warnings it is

```
return (Map<Class<? super C>, A>)(Object)annotationsByClass;
```

This is as elegant as it gets. You had a `Map<Class<?>, A>`, you impose on it an unchecked assertion that all those classes in that map are in fact supertypes of C, and you document that this doesn't need to be checked because the code as written guarantees it. It's always nicer to rely on compiler guaranteed instead, but as explained above, that is simply not possible. You can try to shift things around to avoid that intermediate cast, but that's actually making things worse: This way, you isolate the one and only unchecked assertion you must inject into your code into a single, isolatable (as in, you can shove it in a private method and `@SuppressWarnings` only that), easily documentable one-liner helper method.

### Is `Class` really broken?

Well, the choice of the wonky array-returning methods is suspect, and it might have been better to add superfluous alternative methods that return a `List<Class<? super C>>` instead. However, it's a matter of tradeoffs. Whilst the API in general is a sordid, leaky mess as is, one advantage is that things like `someClass.getConstructor().newInstance()` are helpful in that they at least return the actual type if compiler-known, instead of `Object`.

### Factories!

Note that Class is rarely what you want. `Class` is a core library class you can't change, so, the menu of options it gives is [A] fixed and uneditable, and [B] has shoddy API. For this reason, it tends to be the better option to work with factories instead. Factories are just a 'meta' class whose instance represents what `static` would otherwise represent - things you can do with that type that don't need an instance of it.

A very obvious thing one wants to do, is invoke constructors (which are effectively static methods - they do not require a receiver just like static methods don't need one), but you can generalize that to everything class related: Any other method that feels like it should be static, as well as properties of the class itself, these can all be shoved into a separate implementation that implements an `XFactory` interface. And, crucially, that type hierarchy **can** have sane generics on it.

You did not explain why you need this stuff, but disregard the clichés about how java overuses factories. Those are coming from people that do not understand the value of 'static' but in type hierarchies: Note that just about every wannabe java killer language has them baked straight in (both scala and kotlin have them as core lang features, for example).